# useSubmit is submitting the wrong params

Tags: remix

i'm trying to submit each time i change my input.

when i try to change the input my submit works yet changes the params to this weird looking string:
"http://localhost:3000/items?0=G&1=r&2=e&3=e&4=n&5=+&6=D&7=j&8=i&9=n&10=n"

this is the code

```
export async function action({ request }) {
  const body = await request.formData();
}

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const term = url.searchParams.get('sellers');

  console.log('term:', term);

  const data: LoaderData = {
    itemList: await db.item.findMany({
      where: {
        seller: term,
      },
      select: {
        seller: true,
        price: true,
      },
    }),
  };
  return json(data);
};

type LoaderData = {
  itemList: Array<Item>;
};

export default function ItemsRouteIndex() {
  const submit = useSubmit();
  const { itemList } = useLoaderData<LoaderData>();

  function handleChange(e) {
    console.log('e:', e);
    submit(e, { method: 'get', action: '/items' });
  }

  return (
    <Form onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}>
      <select name='sellers'>
        <option value='Blue Djinn'>Blue Djinn</option>
        <option value='Green Djinn'>Green Djinn</option>
      </select>
      <button type='submit'>Search</button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i tried to submit the value of the event and not the event form.

Here's the fix :

```
      <Form onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.form)}>
        <select name='sellers'>
          <option value='Blue Djinn'>Blue Djinn</option>
          <option value='Green Djinn'>Green Djinn</option>
        </select>
      </Form>
```